# SQL query to find week number based on days of week in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find the week number of given date based on days of week.

For example:

[image]

I am trying using the below query, but unable to calculate it based on the day.

```
select  
        to_char(to_date('20150101','YYYYMMDD')-2,'iw') week_sun_thru_saturday,
        to_number(to_char(to_date('20150101','YYYYMMDD')-1,'iw')) -
        to_number(to_char( to_date('03-jan-2015','dd-mon-yyyy')+1,'iw')) week_from_03_jan_2015
from dual;
```

Comment: Why do you expect March - May of 2015 to bee in week 1 of 2015?  I don't understand your expectations/question.  Same for February 1st of 2015.. why would it even consider being in 2014?

Comment: this is in DD-MM-YYYY format

Comment: Since my week range is starting from Sat to Sun (for 1st column)/ or Sun to Sat (for 2nd column),  and since 1st Jan 2015 is on Thursday, it should show as the previous week number.

Comment: This is business data. Store it in a table.